# Encrypt folders with executable scripts inside

Tags: 18.04, scripts, filesystem, encryption, security

I have ML scripts(python) that need to be up and running. The problem is with protecting the source code and the corresponding model weights. Encrypting doesnt help as I am not able to run the scripts inside without decrypting the folder first. Is there any way to hide/protect the folder containing source code and model weights and still have them running?

In short, I need to hide/protect a folder in Ubuntu with executable scripts inside which need to be run.

Answer (score 0):

You can change **permissions** of the folder and files allowing other users and groups to either view, write or execute the folder and its contents using the `chmod` command.

Use this [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) for more information or use the manual page of `chmod` using `man chmod` in terminal.

Comment: Yes but the problem is I don't want the admin also to access. I am going to deploy this system and so I cant monitor it afterwards.

Comment: On which platform will you deploy it? It depends on different platforms, but I think there must be someone who has access to it i.e there must be at least one admin.

Comment: Platform is Ubuntu. Yes there will be one admin. My requirement is that he shouldnt be able access the folder.